# Mixing some math fonts

Tags: fonts, math-mode, latin-modern, ebgaramond

I want the symbols such `\int` or `\sum` from the Latin Modern Math font and the `\nabla` and all the greek letter such `\alpha \beta \psi` etc from the Latin Modern Math but all numbers and letters from the EB Garamond. How can i do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {EB Garamond}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{EB Garamond} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {EB Garamond}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
\[ \int f(\alpha+x)=\sum\beta \]
Some text\dots
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2 \nabla}{\partial \nabla^2}&=x^2 + yimc^2=z^2 \\
                                           &=\mathrm{x^2 + y^2 = z^2} \\
                                           &=\mathbf{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi }{\partial t}=\frac{\hbar c}{i}\left(\alpha _1\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x^1}+\alpha _2\frac{\partial \Psi }{\partial x^2}+\alpha _3\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x^3}\right)+\alpha _4mc^2\psi
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And the shape of `\partial` how this example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By doing this a large amount of cute furry animals will die horribly, are you really sure this is what you want?

Comment: haha lool is not good idea?

Comment: From `\usepackage{mathptmx}` till `\setmainfont` should be removed as it makes no sense at all with `unicode-math`.

Comment: Also you shouldn’t be loading `amsfonts`, `amssymb` or `type1ec` packages, they too make no sense here.

Comment: @KhaledHosny i have updated my answer, but if i remove `\usepackage{mathptmx}`  the `\hbar` disappears...

Answer (score 3):

You have to carefully select the ranges and the symbols you need. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {EB Garamond}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{EB Garamond} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {EB Garamond}
\setmathfont[range={\partial,\nabla,\hslash}]{TG Termes Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek,Greek}]{Latin Modern Math}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
\[ \int f(\alpha+x)=\sum\beta \]
Some text\dots
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial^2 \nabla}{\partial \nabla^2}&=x^2 + yimc^2=z^2 \\
                                           &=\mathrm{x^2 + y^2 = z^2} \\
                                           &=\mathbf{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi }{\partial t}=\frac{\hbar c}{i}\left(\alpha _1\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x^1}+\alpha _2\frac{\partial \Psi }{\partial x^2}+\alpha _3\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x^3}\right)+\alpha _4mc^2\psi
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t `\mathit` use “EB Garamond Italic”?

Comment: @KhaledHosny I think so, but that's what the OP seemed to want.